# a href issue in chrome

Tags: html, pdf, google-chrome, href

i have a simple web page with a list of links linking to specific pages in a PDF file. This works fine in Firefox, IE 6,7,8,9 but not in chrome?

The code is very simple and works in everything else. In chrome however it just opens the PDf on the first page.

Help please!

Comment: you could do with posting the code.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Reader supports `#page=X` as a postfix to the URL in order to jump to a specific page in a PDF document. Chrome's PDF reader doesn't support this at the moment.

This is a known bug that has been filed as http://crbug.com/65851; please star that bug in order to follow the progress.